# Missing "Vol." and "No." in biblatex/biber

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'd like to cite an article with biblatex, but I'm failing to add "Vol." and "No." in front of the corresponding number.

Here is the entry, of type `@article`, in the `.bib` file:

```
@article{kakimoto_monitoring_2006,
    title = {Monitoring of Interarea Oscillation Mode by Synchronized Phasor Mesurement},
    volume = {21},
    issn = {0885-8950},
    doi = {10.1109/TPWRS.2005.861960},
    number = {1},
    journal = {{IEEE} Transactions on Power Systems},
    author = {Kakimoto, Naoto and Sugumi, Masahiro and Makino, Tohru and Tomiyama, Katsuyuki},
    month = feb,
    year = {2006},
    pages = {260 -- 268}
}
```

I cite it in this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
    adieresis={ä},
    germandbls={ß},
    Euro={€},
}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
% erweiterete Literaturverwaltung
\usepackage[  backend = biber   % (bibtex, biber)
        , bibwarn = true    % Warnung bei fehlerhafter bib-Datei
        , style = authoryear
        , natbib = true
          ]{biblatex}
% Einstellung der Anführungszeichen bei Zitaten („x“, »x«, “x”)
\usepackage[autostyle = true]{csquotes}

% Lokalisierung für biber ergänzen % wirkt nicht
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
      jourvol = {V1ol. }
    , volume = {VolB. }
    , volumes = {VolBs. }
    , edition = {No. }
    %, andothers = {and others}
}
% Trenner zwischen den Namen ein Semikolon
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

% Literaturliste laden
\addbibresource{L:/Uni/Literatur.bib} 

\begin{document}

\cite{kakimoto_monitoring_2006}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

But I get in my bibliography this entry:

```
Kakimoto, Naoto u.a. (Feb. 2006). „Monitoring of Interarea Oscillation Mode by Syn-
chronized Phasor Mesurement“. In: IEEE Transactions on Power Systems 21.1, S. 260–
268. issn: 0885-8950. doi: 10.1109/TPWRS.2005.861960.
```

As you can see, instead of "Vol. 21, No. 1" I get "21.1".

In my code I tried to change this behaviour with the `\DefineBibliographyStrings` macro, but without success. It is interesting, that the commented `andother` localisation string works, the others don't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To make use of the excellent localisation features of `biblatex`, the following approach might be more apt.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}\addnbspace #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace #1}
```

Note the use of a non-breaking space (`\addnbspace`), if you prefer a normal space, go with `\addpspace`.
(*Edit*: One should probably better use `\bibstring{jourvol}` instead of `\bibstring{volume}`, I have changed this, for German at least the output changes, this is not reflected in the image below.)

This, however, results in "Bd. 21.Nr. 1", so we modify the bibmacro `volume+number+eid` a bit to include a comma (and a space) between the volume and number.

```
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%<---- was \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
```

So the MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend = biber,style = authoryear,natbib = true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle = true]{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{kakimoto_monitoring_2006,
    title = {Monitoring of Interarea Oscillation Mode by Synchronized Phasor Mesurement},
    volume = {21},
    issn = {0885-8950},
    doi = {10.1109/TPWRS.2005.861960},
    number = {1},
    journal = {{IEEE} Transactions on Power Systems},
    author = {Kakimoto, Naoto and Sugumi, Masahiro and Makino, Tohru and Tomiyama, Katsuyuki},
    month = feb,
    year = {2006},
    pages = {260 -- 268}
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}\addnbspace #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace #1}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\begin{document}
  \cite{kakimoto_monitoring_2006}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]

---

If you wish to include a comma before the `volume`, add to your preamble.

```
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% was: \setunit*{\addspace}
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}}% was: \setunit{\addspace}
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}
```

Comment: this is perfect, except for a missing comma in front of Bd.! How can we add this?

Comment: @Ingo Have a look a the edited answer. If you want more, it might be better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can see, this is not a localization issue, so `\DefineBibliographyStrings` cannot do anything for you here. You have to modify the field formats. Try:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{Vol. #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{No. #1}
```

You can suppress the optional `[article]` argument if you want this to hold whatever the entry type.

Comment: Thank you! This works. But for what are the localisation string `volume` and `jourvol`?
And what should I do, if I want an edition localised? In german it is "Auflage" and in english "edition"? This doesn't work with your approach, doesn't it?

Comment: To change the localisation for some strings manually, you can do: ```\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers = {et al.},
  jourvol = {Vol.}
}
```