# Biblatex formatting issues

Tags: biblatex

apoligies for the probably simple question but i'm having some issues formatting my bibliography for my honours project. I'm currently using biblatex with these options:

```
\usepackage[firstinits=true,backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

this outputs what I want in the in text referencing (as I am trying to use the "harvard" author-date system).

The issue I am having is that when i print out the bibliography, the following results:

> Adaramola, M. and P.-Å. Krogstad (2011). “Experimental investigation of wake effects on wind turbine performance”. In: Renewable Energy 36, pp. 2078 –2086.

and for the life of me i can't seem to find a way to put 'vol.' before the 36 and get rid of the 'In:' 
is there an option to do this?

I would probably prefer to leave it as is but the other format is required by my university.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I've taken the liberty of replacing several instances of "bibtex" with "biblatex", as your posting appears to be about biblatex rather than bibtex. For a pointer on how to get of "In:" see, e.g., [Suppress "In:" biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/5001). For adding the string "vol" see, e.g., [Missing “Vol.” and “No.” in biblatex/biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97376/5001).

Comment: Legend, Cheers!