# Issues with Bibtex in elsarticle

Tags: bibtex, miktex, elsarticle

I am facing some issues with bibtex in elsarticle. Below is the bibtex file-

```
@misc{EducationData,
  title        = {Education},
  howpublished = {\url{http://data.worldbank.org/topic/education?display=graph}},
  note         = {[Online; accessed: 2014-09-23]}
}

@inproceedings{PMistrySIGGRAPH,
    author       = {P Mistry and P Maes},
    title        = {Sixth{S}ense - {A} {W}earable {G}estural {I}nterface},
    booktitle    = {Proceedings of SIGGRAPH Asia},
    address      = {Yokohama, Japan},
    organization = {Emerging Technologies},
    pages        = {0-0},
    year         = {2009}
}

@article{Mignonneau2005,
  title   = {Designing emotional, metaphoric, natural and intuitive interfaces for interactive art, edutainment and mobile communications},
  journal = {Computers \& Graphics},
  volume  = {29},
  pages   = {837-851},
  year    = {2005},
  author  = {L Mignonneau and C Sommerer}
}

@book{CynthiaSmith,
    author    = {Cynthia E. Smith},
    title     = {Design For The Other 90\%},
    year      = {2007},
    publisher = {Editions Assouline}
}
```

Below is the output-
[image]

Following are the issues, which I am facing-

1. While referring a website URL, I am getting following error while compiling "Warning--empty year in EducationData; set to ????". Please see 1st entry in the attached output.
2. Unable to remove field `pages` from `inproceedings` section. Getting following error, after removing `pages` field "Warning--empty pages in PMistrySIGGRAPH"
3. Unable to distinguish among the various fields in the generated PDF. Please try to differentiate between author's name and title in the 2nd and 3rd entry in the attached output.
4. Prefix pp, vol., no. are nowhere visible in the generated PDF

For the issue (4), I referred [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97378/49520) but I get stuck after getting the following error "! Undefined control sequence." Below is the snippet of tex file (You may find some of the unnecessary packages declaration, which I am using in original version)-

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nodots]{numcompress}
\usepackage{lineno}
\setlength\linenumbersep{3pt}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
%% Writing C#
\newcommand{\Csharp}{%
  {\settoheight{\dimen0}{C}C\kern-.05em \resizebox{!}{\dimen0}{\raisebox{\depth}{\#}}}}

\journal{Computers \& Graphics}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter} 
    \title{A Sample Paper written in \LaTeX ~using elsarticle}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{INTRODUCTION}
This is created just for demonstration purpose \cite{EducationData}. Following are some more references \cite{PMistrySIGGRAPH} and \cite{Mignonneau2005} . The reference of a book goes here \cite{CynthiaSmith}.

\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}
\bibliography{Sample}

\end{document}
```

I am using Texmaker 4.1.1 with MiKTeX 2.9 in Windows 7 32 bit OS.

Comment: Your posting is not compilable, and it is not exactly minimal either. Some comments: (i) Entries of type `@misc` *require* `author` and `year` fields. (ii) What do the two `\DeclareFieldFormat` directives do? (iii) Which bibliography style do you use? (iv) For entries of type `@inproceedings`, the `pages` field is optional; if you don't want to show pages for a particular entry, don't provide the `pages` field. (v) Not directly related to the topic of your posting, but still of relevance: The `subfigure` package is deprecated: Don't use it. Use the `subcaption` or the `subfig` package instead.

Comment: More on using the macro `\DeclareFieldFormat`: It requires the use of `biblatex`. Since you're not loading that package, you can't use `\DeclareFieldFormat`.

Comment: Also, for (3), you need to use a different style (or adapt one) if you want a different style. That is, if your current style puts titles of articles in without quotation marks, for example, and you want quotation marks, you need to use a style which uses them.

Comment: @Mico: Apologies for the inconvenience . Please see the updated question.

Comment: @cfr: Apologies for the inconvenience . Please see the updated question.