# How to transfor "t." into "vol." with the french version of citeyear?

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, french

I use the package :

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear, language=french]{biblatex}
```

I have followed the instructions given for this precedent question [Missing “Vol.” and “No.” in biblatex/biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97376/missing-vol-and-no-in-biblatex-biber) to add the terms Vol. and N° in the references section.

But once I have used :  `

`\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}\addnbspace #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace #1}`

I get for instance :

> Howard, Sue ; John Dryden et Bruce Johnson (sept. 1999), « Childhood Resilience: review and critique of literature », in : Oxford Review of Education, t. 25, no 3

How to transform the "**t**." into "**Vol.**" without having to switch into the english version of authoryear ?

Comment: `\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{volume = {vol\adddot}}` should do it, if you want to change both the short and long version of the bibstring you will need to create your own `.lbx` file though.

Comment: I voted to close this question as duplicate of [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864) since the solution is explained in the comprehensive answer there, I was however not really sure whether said question is really a duplicate-able question, so feel free to disagree.